# Why am I getting "Trailing Garbage - NaN" errors with the output of my d3.json?

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm loading data using d3.json then presenting it to a display - which is giving the right output variable when I use console.log(variable) but seemingly dragging along a lot of other stuff from the json file in my output.

```
function NewValue(){
  var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
  callbacks.add( GetDataFromJson );
  callbacks.fire();
  return 
}

function GetDataFromJson() {
  var jsonData;
  var myTotal;
d3.json("http://localhost:8000/pipeline.json", function(dataFromServer){
    jsonData = dataFromServer;
    headers = ["Won"];
      chunks = (headers.map(function(priceRange) {
          return jsonData.map(function(d) {
            return {y: +d[priceRange]};
          });
      }));
      var myTarget = 10000000;
      chunks.forEach( function (arrayItem)
          {
            var l = 12;
            for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
              var x = arrayItem[i].y;
              myTotal +=x;
            };
          });
      myTotal = myTotal/myTarget*100;
     // console.log(myTotal);
      return myTotal;
 });
}
```

I'm loading it to a d3.liquidFillGauge - and getting this result:

```
d3.v3.min.js:4 Error: <g> attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "….33333333333334,NaN)".
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit - adding json file:**

```
[
  {
    "Month": "Jan",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 1000000,
    "Lost": 350000
  },
  {
    "Month": "Feb",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 750000,
    "Lost": 2750775
  },
  {
    "Month": "Mar",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 250000,
    "Won": 2000000,
    "Lost": 750000
  },
  {
    "Month": "Apr",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 1375000,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "May",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 750000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Jun",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 325000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Jul",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 50000,
    "Demonstrating": 1000000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Aug",
    "Prospecting": 10000,
    "Qualifying": 35000,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Sep",
    "Prospecting": 12250,
    "Qualifying": 22500,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Oct",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Nov",
    "Prospecting": 100000,
    "Qualifying": 325000,
    "Demonstrating": 750000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Dec",
    "Prospecting": 120000,
    "Qualifying": 370500,
    "Demonstrating": 670000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: can you upload your json file ?

Comment: @Dragon_Slayer - yes, I've uploaded/edited it now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get the following error running the same script in Firefox: Unexpected value translate(-38.33333333333334,NaN) parsing transform attribute.